# Flutter - Send params in Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

I have two different pages. One of these is a form, the other is a list of elements. If you swipe one of the elements to left can edit. I need to send the  element data (from the list) to first page (the form)

When the application starts the data is null, if it come from the element list isn´t null.

The navigation bar code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:datameter/screens/configuration/form/partials/home_page.dart';
import 'package:datameter/screens/configuration/list/datameters.dart';
import 'package:datameter/locations/locations.dart';

class Navigation extends StatefulWidget {

 final item;

  Navigation(
      {Key key,
      this.item})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _NavigationState();
  }
}

class _NavigationState extends State<Navigation> {

  int currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> children = [
    HomePageScreen(datameter: widget.item), //ERRROR HERE
    DatametersPageScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: children[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            primaryColor: Colors.blue[700],
            textTheme: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            onTap: onTabTapped,
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                title: Text(DemoLocalizations.of(context).text('new-device')),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                title: Text(DemoLocalizations.of(context).text('show-all')),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

When I try to send params from elements list (using navigation bottom bar)  to the form, returns

> Static only members can be accessed in initializers.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**_NavigationState** Object is not constructed so you cannot access  "widget" getter yet because its not initialized and its not static property either.

change

```
 List<Widget> children = [
    HomePageScreen(datameter: widget.item), //ERRROR HERE
    DatametersPageScreen(),
  ];
```

to

```
 List<Widget> _children() =>
 [   
    HomePageScreen(datameter: widget.item),
    DatametersPageScreen(),
 ];
```

and then in your build change

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context)
{
    final List<Widget> children = _children();

    return Scaffold
    (
        //code
        body: children[currentIndex],
        //code
    );
}
```

Comment: @Anjumohan glad

Comment: Simple and amazing. What other approaches we can use to solve this?