# How to pass variables inside bottomNavigationBar tabs

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement `bottomNavigationBar`, but I need to pass a variable that i get from another page, to one of the tabs.

I tired access via `widget`, but it didn't work.

How can i solve it?

```
 class BottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
      int num;

      BottomNavigationBar(this.num);
      @override
      _BottomNavigationBarState createState() => _BottomNavigationBarState();
    }

    class _BottomNavigationBarState extends State<BottomNavigationBar> {
    int currentTabIndex = 0;
      List<Widget> tabs = [
        PageA(widget.num),  //The problem
        PageB(),
        PageC()
      ];
```

Comment: Could you please post how you initialize the **BottomNavigationBar** widget in your code and the code for the **PageA** class?

Comment: you should use a state manager to track that information and then it would be accessible throughout the app and more specifically the various tabs - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56659009/122313

Comment: This is the solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073495/3312425

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a variable on your State class

```
 class BottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  int num;

  BottomNavigationBar(num);
  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarState createState() => _BottomNavigationBarState(num);
}

class _BottomNavigationBarState extends State<BottomNavigationBar> {

int num;

_BottomNavigationBarState(num);


int currentTabIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> tabs = [
    PageA(this.num),  //The problem
    PageB(),
    PageC()
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `initState` to assign values. Here is what you are missing.

```
class _BottomNavigationBarState extends State<BottomNavigationBar> {
  int currentTabIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> tabs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabs = [
      PageA(widget.num) // no problem now
      PageB(),
      PageC()
    ];
  }

....

}
```